# Dictionary does not have a member named 'allKeys' - swift2 getting all dictionary keys failing with error

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, swift2

I am having some problems getting an array of keys for a `Dictionary` - this will be used in a `UITableView` data model

For the top level table, I expect a count of 3 and the keys: GMRS, IRLP, and WinSystem

**The code:**

```
let rows = repeaterInfoDict.count // 3
let keyArray = repeaterInfoDict.allKeys // Error: [String:[String:[String:Any]]] does not have a member named 'allKeys'
```

.count received 3, but .allKeys is erring out with the Xcode error: [String:[String:[String:Any]]] does not have a member named 'allKeys'

**Some detail on the dictionary:**

repeaterInfoDict definition:

var repeaterInfoDict = String:[String:[String:Any]]

What the dictionary looks like after AWS CognitoSync has completed it's sync:

**Console:**

`print ("repeaterInfoDict: \(repeaterInfoDict)")` - added whitespace formatting for easy viewing.

repeaterInfoDict:

```
[
 GMRS: 
  [
   1121: [no: "San Jose,CA", pl: 0.0, lt: 37.33939, fq: 462.550, ln: -121.89496, ca: "WPUI299"], 
   1011: [no: "Napa,CA", pl: 0.0, lt: 38.29714, fq: 462.575, ln: -122.28553, ca: "wqbk788"], 
   1104: [no: "Palmdale,CA", pl: 0.0, lt: 34.57943, fq: 462.65, ln: -118.11646, ca: "WQHR999"]
  ], 
 IRLP: 
  [
    1121: [no: "St. Andrews,MB", pl: 127.3, lt: 114.3245, fq: 0.62, ln: 33.2345, ca: "VE4COR"],
    1011: [no: "Birken,BC", pl: 100.0, lt: 114.3245, fq: 147.0, ln: 33.2345, ca: "VA7IP"],
    1104: [no: "Saskatoon,SK", pl: 100.0, lt: 52.11679, fq: 446.1, ln: -106.63452, ca: "VE5RNP"]
  ], 
 WinSystem: 
  [
    1121: [no: "Los Angeles,CA", pl: -100.0, lt: 34.05223, fq: 448.06, ln: -118.24368, ca: "K6JSI"],
    1011: [no: "Escondido,CA", pl: -100.0, lt: 33.11921, fq: 449.08, ln: -117.08642, ca: "K6JSI"],
    1104: [no: "San Diego,CA", pl: -100.0, lt: 32.71533, fq: 447.64, ln: -117.15726, ca: "K6JSI"]
  ]
]

print ("repeaterInfoDict.count: \(repeaterInfoDict.count)")
repeaterInfoDict.count: 3
```

1. At the first level table, I expect 3 rows and keys: GMRS, IRLP, WinSystems
2. At the second level table for IRLP, I expect 3 rows and keys: 1121, 1011, 1104
3. At the third level table for 1121, I expect to format the `Dictionary`
   [no: "Los Angeles,CA", pl: -100.0, lt: 34.05223, fq: 448.06, ln:
   -118.24368, ca: "K6JSI"] into a custom cell/view

What is the correct/best way of getting the keys in this nested `Dictionary`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you don't need all of them in a single array. Then I suggest you loop over the items with the keys that you receive from the `keys` property (not `allKeys`).

```
for key in dictionary.keys {
    for nestedKey in dictionary[key].keys {
        for nested2Key in dictionary[key][nestedKey].keys {
            // use the keys
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that this will not be sorted like you entered, `Dictionary` does not store an order.

Comment: Your right, it does not need to be in a single nested `Dictionary`, I can break id down after CognitoSync finishes. But it is already decoded from the JSON input and seems like a nice structure. Still trying to figure out why .count works, but .allKeys does not.

Comment: @Kent `allKeys` is not defined on a Swift Dictionary. Use `keys` to get an array of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Replaced:

`let keyArray = repeaterInfoDict.allKeys`

With:

`let keyArray = repeaterInfoDict.keys.array`

Now when I `print("** keyArray: \(keyArray)")` I get:

`** keyArray: [GMRS, IRLP, WinSystem]`

I do not know why `repeaterInfoDict.allKeys` did not return this array.

Any better solutions?

Comment: This should be an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31019167/edit) to the question instead of an answer. Only use the answers section if you have a solution to the problem